# Port Knocking using javascript works well on Linux but not in Windows

Tags: javascript, security, fetch-api

I'm securing a web application and I'm implementing the port knocking technique. The server side implementation is running and i'm making a small desktop application to make the "knocking" on the ports. 
I decided to do this with javascript and the fetch API currently available on most browsers.

To make a test, I opened a browser and wrote the following function:

```
(async function() {
    for ( port of [7000, 8000, 9000] ) { 
       await fetch("https://xx.xx.xx.xx:" + port)
           .catch(() => console.log("packet sent on port ", port)) 
           // I only catch because the server rejects the connection.
           // With the TCP SYN sent it's enough.
    }
})();
```

Running this on Chrome over Ubuntu 18.10 works exactly as expected, but when I copied this function to a Windows 7 computer, **the fetch behavior is somehow random:**

When looking on the server logs I realize that there are multiple connections for every port (not a constant) and sometimes the order changed.

The normal behavior running this on my Linux computer:

```
openWeb: Stage 1
openWeb: Stage 2
openWeb: Stage 3
```

When running on a Windows-based machine:

```
openWeb: Stage 1
openWeb: Stage 1
openWeb: Stage 1
openWeb: Stage 2
openWeb: Stage 1
openWeb: Stage 1
openWeb: Stage 1
closeWeb: Stage 1
closeWeb: Stage 2
closeWeb: Stage 1
closeWeb: Stage 1
```

The order of the connections is important and thus this is not working on the knock listener daemon.

Used Chrome Dev Tools to analize network activity and there is nothing strange in how connections are displayed there.

---

**UPDATE:** Used the **net** module instead of **node-fetch** and got the same result.

Comment: *indows 7 was released in 2009. Have you filed a bug? Does the same behaviour occur at *indows 10?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the server rejection. Is there any possible way to open those ports and send dummy data back instead? Then maybe Windows behavior would be the same. Also have you tested to make sure Windows is not blocking that network activity?

Comment: Tested on Windows 10, and the same happens. Maybe if i open these ports and put a listener this would work but is not what i need.